# Can't get a managedQuery with selection to work

Tags: android, sqlite, select, selection

In my Android program, I'm trying to use a managedQuery with a selection argument, but I get an Sql exception.

```
07-26 19:30:44.364: INFO/Database(1163): 
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ".": syntax error
```

Here is my example code

```
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                      MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                      MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
                      MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC };

     // Example without selection, works
     String selection = null;
     Cursor musiccursor = managedQuery(
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, selection, null,
                  null);

     // Example with selection, does not work
     selection = "MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID = 1";
     musiccursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, selection, null,
                null);
```

Thanks, Niclas

Answer (score 1):

The selection should be initialized like this:

selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID+" = 1";

If you include the MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID in quotes the constant name is sent to SQLite to evaluate instead of actual column name _id.